# Negative GID in /etc/passwd?

Tags: linux, debian, login, group, passwd

I got following entries in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/passwd-` on one system:

```
userfoo:x:501:-513::/home/userfoo:/bin/false
```

There's no group 513 anywhere on the system.
What's this "negative" gid or a gid with a dash prefix?
Is this some kind of convention?

It seems that dash/negative alone is the reason this user is not recognised, e.g. by `passwd -S`.

I went ahead and manually edited `-513` to `9999` (some non-existent group id) and user entry is fine now (it was not a real user, just a helper).

I'd like to know how it could have happened?

P.S. it's a debian-based linux system.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a bug... (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=39679)

Which adduser package version is istalled on your system?

```
dpkg -l | grep adduser
```

Comment: Well, that's interesting. I'm not running Hurd kernel though. I doubt gid was supplied explicitly at all, yet I'm still to validate that.

Comment: Version is `adduser  3.113+nmu3`